# Rails Routing Error - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've been through the Rails Guide and additional docs to better understand routing, but I'm at a loss for why the following won't work.

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"preferences", :controller=>"users"}
```

I've added the following additional methods (they aren't complete yet) to my users_controller:

```
def preferences
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update_pref
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, :notice => 'Updated Preferences.'
    else
      flash.alert = 'Unable to update preferences.'
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

My routes.rb contains,

```
resources :users do
    member do
      get 'preferences'
      put 'update_pref'
    end
```

end

And when I run rake:routes, I get,

```
 preferences_user GET    /users/:id/preferences(.:format)   users#preferences                                                                                                  
        update_pref_user PUT    /users/:id/update_pref(.:format)   users#update_pref                                                                                                  
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                   users#index                                                                                                        
                         POST   /users(.:format)                   users#create                                                                                                       
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)               users#new                                                                                                          
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)          users#edit                                                                                                         
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)               users#show                                                                                                         
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)               users#update                                                                                                       
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)               users#destroy
```

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: It might be expecting an id as well.  what if you use the named route, eg `link_to preferences_user_path(@user)`?  Does that work?  Can you add the code for the link_to or however you're generating the url?

Comment: Can you provide more details on where this error occurs? Is it a form or a link or something else?

Comment: Can you share the view from where you are calling this path and get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'preferences' # comment or remove
    put 'update_pref'
  end
end
```

**one way**

```
get '/preferences' => 'users#preferences'
```

now you can use:

```
  preferences_path
```

the way you put it in member it expects an id:

```
preferences_user_path(user)
```

**another way**

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'preferences'
  end
end
```

and you'll have `users/preferences` available without needing to pass `user` object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the user object to the url.

like user

```
 preferences_user_path(@user)
```

This will create an url like users/1/preferences

Please visit documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions